# Android application name with superscript

Tags: android, superscript

How can I make the application name in superscript, I've tried this way:

```
<string name="app_name">SomeApp <sup><small><b>beta</b></small></sup></string>
```

it works on TextView's but it doesn't work on the application name.

Something like this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use ISO-8859-1 / UTF-8 characters to accomplish inserting (in your case) a superscript 3.

List of 
[HTML ISO-8859-1 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) entities.

For example in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Myapp³" <!--or reference it from @string -->
```

Or use the HTML entity `&#xb3;` (hex) `&#179;` (dec) somewhere in a String, like:

```
<string name="app_name">Myapp&#179;</string>
```

### Small compilation of Unicode reference tables

[Unicode 6.2 Character Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)

- [C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) (ranges 0080-00FF where superscript resides)
- [General Punctuation](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf)
- [CJK Symbols and Punctuation](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3000.pdf)
- [CJK Compatibility Forms](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFE30.pdf)
- [Small Form Variants](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFE50.pdf)
- [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf)

(from wikipedia)

Comment: So if want to write "beta" I need to find the 4 characters in the ISO-8859-1 and put them together right?

Comment: Do you mean the actual word "beta", or the greek letter Beta (`ß`)? If  you just mean the word "beta", you would just type it as you would normally.

Comment: I mean the word "beta" but with the equivalent of "ApplicationX<sup>beta</sup>" in html

Comment: I don't think that's possible in a regular string, using HTML. It is however possible in a `TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("ApplicationX<sup>beta</sup>"));`

Comment: If I was you, I'd use the greek letter Beta (`β`) instead of spending time trying to get the word beta superscripted. Anyone knowing the correlation between the word Beta and pre-release software, should also know of the greek letter Beta. I used the `β` (dec 225) symbol to denote Beta software back in the days of DOS-programs.